# I couldn't find any practical use of the `clipBehavior` property of the `DataTable` widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, datatable, widget

I couldn't find any practical use of the `clipBehavior` property of the `DataTable` widget in flutter. I have read the docs but, I don't see it work. When applied, it doesn't make any changes to the Table, it just remains the same. Here is the code snippet.

```
 DataTable theDataTable() {
  return DataTable(
      // decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 20)),
      // clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      showBottomBorder: true,
      showCheckboxColumn: true,
      checkboxHorizontalMargin: 50,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('ID'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Name'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Phone'),
        ),
      ],
      rows: [
        DataRow(
          // color: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.pink),
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text('1'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text('Mohan'),
              placeholder: true,
            ),
            DataCell(
              // ATTENTION: The long text below remains same with or without the clipBehavior property
              Text(
                  'This is a very long description that might not fit within the table without clipping.'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text('2'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text('Drek'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text('1234567899'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          onSelectChanged: (value) {},
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text('3'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text('Shean'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text('1234567899'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]);
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a specific question, or described what you specifically expect to see (and why you expect to see it).

Comment: Are you mixing up "clipping", as related to image/shape/graphics manipulation, with simple text truncation? The latter is typically handled by the CSS [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property - including how to handle long text in narrow HTML table cells.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to achieve anything here, I am trying to understand why are we given this property if it is not doing anything. I am unable to figure out its usage.